# Using meta learning in RWeka

Tags: java, r, stat

I used [RWeka](http://bit.ly/gwXeKU) to call Weka functions directly in R.

I tried using meta learning (bagging) but failed.

My code is `Bagging(classLabel ~ ., data = train, control = Weka_control(W = J48))`
However, the following error pops up:

```
Error in Bagging(classLabel ~ ., data = train, control = Weka_control(W = J48)) : 
  unused argument(s) (data = train, control = Weka_control(W = J48))
```

I also tried several different base learners but always met such error.

If you successfully used meta learning in RWeka before, please let me know.

Comment: Just tried another writing `optns <- Weka_control(W = "weka.classifiers.trees.REPTree")   
Bagging <- make_Weka_classifier("weka/classifiers/meta/Bagging")  
model <- Bagging(classLabel ~ ., data=dat, control = optns)` Surprisingly the R code works now.

Comment: Post this as an answer and mark it as the solution. Maybe it will save someone's time who won't have to read your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried another writing:

`optns <- Weka_control(W = "weka.classifiers.trees.REPTree") Bagging <- make_Weka_classifier("weka/classifiers/meta/Bagging") model <- Bagging(classLabel ~ ., data=dat, control = optns)`

Surprisingly the R code works now.
-Credit Leo5188

Comment: I posted this as an answer as many of my friends have read this page for their problems. So for others mark this as an answer of post if your self.